# Why's Glassfish so laggy at times?

Tags: windows-server-2008, glassfish

I've got GlassFish running as a service on a Windows Server (2008 R2).  If you're actively using GlassFish, it stays nice and fast.  However, if you go away and don't use it for several minutes, when you come back, *any* Glassfish activity (app or admin panel) takes around 60 seconds to start up.  During that delay period, the server is showing completely idle, as if it hasn't noticed the request yet.  At the end of the time, there's a quick processor spike as GlassFish handles the request.

Not sure where else to go with debugging this problem.  It wasn't like this when originally installed.  Happened sometime in the last few months.  Hard to say when as I only use it rarely, and the end users are overly tolerant of slow computers.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm afraid I can't answer the "why".  I eventually ended up shutting down that old glassfish install.  I then installed a fresh new copy alongside (different directory) and ran that.  Reuploaded all our apps and it's been running perfectly fine.  I've also done significant testing on various VMs with glassfish and am unable to duplicate the problem.  Seems confined to that one particular install (which was done with defaults).  So, perhaps a damaged file or something?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that Windows is just being overly-aggressive about swapping out unused memory pages. You'll see this type of behavior with nearly any application (on many OSes) after a period of un-use, but swapping out after a couple minutes seems odd.

Have any other applications and/or load been installed on this server since Glassfish was originally installed? It is possible that memory demand is much higher and as such, Windows is being more aggressive about swapping out unused pages.

Comment: It's got 8 GiB dedicated to it (another variable I just thought of is that it's a VM on one of our VMWare ESXi hosts).  Runs around 1.5 GiB committed RAM (out of 15, counting default swap).  Only app change I can think of is a change in Anti-virus vendors, however, the AV engine doesn't seem to be generating any load at all.  I'll see if I can try disabling it for testing anyways.